# how to navigate to another screen with react-navigation when the token is fetched and stored

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

After setup 2 screens with react-navigation. The first screen there is a Login and on button pressed fetch the token from the server. And I need to navigate to another screen only when fetch and the token is stored. All I found at react-navigation docs is a solution with button and navigation header, but it's not this case.

I've tried to place the redirect prop inside the function but did not worked.

Please someone has any hint to spare?

Thanks a lot!

here is the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, View, StyleSheet, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Card, Button, CardSection, Input, Spinner } from '../components';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const AUTH_TOKEN = 'auth_token';

class Login extends Component {


    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            email: "",
            password: "",
            error: ""
        }

    }

   storeToken(responseData){
    AsyncStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, responseData, (err)=> {
      if(err){
        console.log("Something went wrong");
        throw err;
      }
      console.log("Success");
    }).catch((err)=> {
        console.log("error is: " + err);
    });
  }






    async onLoginPressed() {

        try {
            let response = await fetch('https://las.herokuapp.com/api/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',

                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    session: {
                        email: this.state.email,
                        password: this.state.password,

                    }
                })
            });
            let res = await response.text();
            if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                let authToken = res;
                console.log(authToken);
                this.storeToken(authToken);
              SHOULD REDIRECT ----> //this.props.navigation.navigate('Home'); 


            } else {
                let error = res;
                throw error;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            this.setState({ error: error });
            console.log("Error" + error);


        }
    }





    render() {

        return (

     <Card>
           <Text> Login </Text> 

            <CardSection>           
            <Input onChangeText = {
                (text) => this.setState({ email: text }) }

            placeholder = "Email" />         
            </CardSection>

            <CardSection>

             <Input onChangeText = {
                (text) => this.setState({ password: text }) } secureTextEntry = { true } placeholder = "Password"/>

            </CardSection> 

            <CardSection>           
            <Button 


            onPress={this.onLoginPressed.bind(this)}>


            Log in            
            </Button> 
            </CardSection>


            <Text style={styles.error}> { this.state.error }  </Text>  






             </Card>


        );

    }

}
```

Comment: First can you check is your 
//this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
working or not , it actual redirecting to page

Comment: @ashutoshpandey in the logs show:

Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: It seems that you have problem in you home component , can you check is that componet is rendering on screen if you try to import from file location and then render it . Please check that , as i sure you have problem with home component

Comment: @ashutoshpandey well, i tested other components and the same

Comment: update you router and home page code then ,

Answer (score 0):

You should navigate after token saved as show in below code :

```
  storeToken(responseData){
    AsyncStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, responseData, (err)=> {
      if(err){
        console.log("Something went wrong");
        throw err;
      } else{
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home'); 
        console.log("Success");
      }
    }).catch((err)=> {
        console.log("error is: " + err);
    });
  }
```

Home screen code :

```
render() {
    return <View/>
}
```

Comment: thank for you interest and answer but in the log show:

Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: AUTH_TOKEN). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: I think the problem with your Home component.

Comment: CrazyVK, i tested other components and the same

Comment: please check after update home screen as in my answer.

Comment: CrazyVk i created a test component and the same.




import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';




class Test extends Component {



  render() {
    return (

<View/>
         
     

    );
  }
}

export default Test;